# Variance of Weighted Mean: Formula vs Bootstrapping

Tags: r, variance, mean

**I am interested in learning about how to calculate the Standard Deviation of the Weighted Mean.**

From Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance, https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/0224c1c53591c619794682f2bc3560dc86530e2b), I obtained the formula for the Weighted Mean:

$$\mu_x = \frac{1}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} \left(\sum_i N_{x_i} \mu_{x_i}\right)$$

$$\sigma_x = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} - 1\right) \sum_i \left[(N_{x_i} - 1)\sigma^2_{x_i} + N_{x_i}\mu^2_{x_i}\right] - \left[\sum_i N_{x_i}\right]\mu^2_x}$$

Since the  Variance of the Mean is equal to the Variance of X divided by sample size, I think you should be able to adapt this formula to calculate the Standard Deviation of the Weighted Mean like this:

$$ \sigma_{\bar{x}} = \frac{\sigma_x}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} = \frac{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} - 1\right) \sum_i \left[(N_{x_i} - 1)\sigma^2_{x_i} + N_{x_i}\mu^2_{x_i}\right] - \left[\sum_i N_{x_i}\right]\mu^2_x}}{\sum_i N_{x_i}}$$

**Now, I am trying to confirm if what I have done is correct.**

Suppose I have this dataset in R which contains the sample mean, variance of the sample mean and sample size for a group of cities:

```
df = structure(list(N_xi = c(4120L, 1625L, 4885L, 4095L, 3560L, 3940L, 
3390L, 2245L, 4615L, 4315L, 3330L, 5085L, 6395L, 2515L, 2595L, 
3400L, 3260L, 4560L, 2320L, 2755L), mu_xi = c(71100L, 109000L, 
74600L, 133200L, 128000L, 91300L, 102500L, 169000L, 96400L, 103600L, 
117600L, 74900L, 88500L, 97800L, 137000L, 103400L, 94200L, 83800L, 
97900L, 109000L), sigma2_xi = c(17340.37563, 34357.14686, 28331.53559, 
65836.85976, 45266.8106, 46644.72409, 34488.63432, 142796.9963, 
105193.3962, 69626.62771, 71367.20046, 32616.67612, 79785.14219, 
39352.22193, 86820.86048, 191484.2953, 34418.06533, 18949.11971, 
38041.609, 65462.82934)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

**Part 1:** I can calculate the Standard Deviation using the adapted formula from above:

```
mu_x <- sum(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) df$N_xi[i] * df$mu_xi[i])) / sum(df$N_xi)

factor1 = (df$N_xi - 1) * (df$sigma2_xi) + df$N_xi*df$mu_xi^2 
factor2 = sum(df$N_xi) * mu_x^2

part1 = sqrt((sum(factor1) - factor2) / (sum(df$N_xi) - 1)) 
part2 =  sqrt(sum(df$N_xi))

final = part1/part2
[1] 81.47042
```

**Part 2:** To me this number seemed a bit low - so I decided to try and use bootstrapping to estimate the Standard Deviation:

```
library(dplyr)

my_list = list()

for(i in 1:100000)
{

sampled_df <- df %>% sample_n(nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
mu_x_i <- sum(sapply(1:nrow(sampled_df), function(i) sampled_df$N_xi[i] * sampled_df$mu_xi[i])) / sum(sampled_df$N_xi)
my_list[[i]] = mu_x_i
print(i)
}

f = do.call(rbind, my_list)
#quantile(f, c(0.05, 0.95))
sqrt(var(f))
[1] 4897.309
```

The estimate from Part 2 seems a lot more reasonable compared to the estimate from Part 1.

**I am now trying to understand why there is such a large difference between the estimate from Part 1 compared to Part 2.**

The only thing that comes to mind is that perhaps I incorrectly derived the formula for the Variance of the Weighted Mean - and in fact, I need to divide by the "number of total cities" and not the "total number of observations in each city", i.e.

```
mu_x <- sum(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) df$N_xi[i] * df$mu_xi[i])) / sum(df$N_xi)
    
    factor1 = (df$N_xi - 1) * (df$sigma2_xi) + df$N_xi*df$mu_xi^2 
    factor2 = sum(df$N_xi) * mu_x^2
    
    part1 = sqrt((sum(factor1) - factor2) / (sum(df$N_xi) - 1)) 
    part2 =  sqrt(nrow(df))
    
    final = part1/part2

[1] 4922.223
```

Now the estimates from both approaches seem to be closer to one another - however, I am still not sure if what I am doing is correct.

**Can someone please help me understand this?**

Thanks!